# Graphql server + NodeJS, store data in cache with Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, graphql

I'd like to know how I can improve the response time from connecting graphql to api. I have decided to use Redis. I don't know how exactly should I do it.

I have built my graphql server:

```
import express from 'express';
import {
    graphqlExpress,
    graphiqlExpress,
} from 'graphql-server-express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { schema } from './src/schema';
import cors from 'cors';

import redis from 'redis';

const PORT = 4000;
const server = express();

const client = redis.createClient();

client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('error' + err)
});

server.use('*', cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));

server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
    schema, context: { client }
}));


server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql'
}));



server.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

I have already imported redis here. My graphql server is connected to front page by cors, so I can render strings from api. In resolver I'm connecting to api by Node.js (if necessary I'll add it.), and I have some custom resolvers here. The response time from api (also affect rendering on page) is too slow- around 10~15s.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out [Apollo Engine](https://www.apollographql.com/engine) to get a better insight into how GraphQL is working, and make it easier to use add-ons such as a Redis cache. Once you get Apollo Engine working, you can use [`apollo-server-redis-cache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-redis-cache) to create a cache.

If your requests are taking 10-15s without a cache, I would also look to optimise them first before throwing Redis in front of them.

Comment: The problem is, time response on page is lower than that in Insomnia. Response time from insomnia (I'm connected to Test Magento2 Server Rest API) is 29-30s. This is too high. Also, I have another Magento2 server API, but this response time is INSANELY hight (insomnia 11.2 min). The problem is on the api side, totally not optimized, I think.